# "Start VM Azure" stage is pending for Node to be available

Tags: windows, azure, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, virtual-machine

Pipeline is stuck because the stage "Test app" is pending for $Node to be available but $Node should be started by "Start VM Azure Machine" stage...
How to workarround this?

```
pipeline {
agent {label 'master'}
stages {
    stage("Start VM Azure Machine"){
        steps{
            build(job: 'Run_or_Stop_Azure_VM', parameters: [string(name:'start_or_deallocate', value: 'start'), string(name: 'Node', value:"${NODE}")] )
        }}          
    stage("Test app"){
        steps {
            build(job:'App install', parameters: [string(name: 'Node', value:"${NODE}")] )
        }}
    stage("Deallocate the machine"){
        steps{
            build(job: 'Run_or_Stop_Azure_VM', parameters: [string(name:'start_or_deallocate', value: 'stop'), string(name: 'Node', value:"${NODE}")] )
        }}  
}}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Stage "Start..." does not launch the VM node? Then it should report an error to stop the pipeline.

Comment: @zett42 Stage "Start VM.." is not started, because pipeline is pending for $Node to be online. Paradox...
stage("Test app") needs online $Node to be started

Comment: Please add detail what job "Run_or_Stop_Azure_VM" is doing.

Comment: Its parametrized FreeStyle Project:
Taking two strings: start_or_deallocate, Node ;
Restrict where this project can be run: master ;
Executing shell command: 
az vm ${start_or_deallocate} --resource-group "resGroup" --name "${Node}" ;

Comment: Okay, I have figured it out.
Changed the: `This project is parameterized: Node` to
`This project is parameterized: String`. issue resolved

Comment: Well, if you solve the issue, please add an answer to display it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have figured it out.
Changed the:

> This project is parameterized: Node

to

> This project is parameterized: String.

issue resolved